# Add an external lib to my Browserify bundle

Tags: javascript, browserify

I know it's a question that has been asked several times. However, I don't find any solution.

I'm using Gulp with Browserify to handle my app JS assets. So my main JS Gulp task looks like this:

```
  return b.bundle()
  .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, uglify()))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder+'/js'));
```

In app.js, I'm making regular require() calls from libs that I handle with NPM (so, with a package.json).

My question: on a project I had to buy a library (...), so I downloaded the files, but now, I don't know how to add them in a clean way and bundle it to my project and existing libs.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I assume that you're also using `require()` to load that library?

Comment: Yes, I really would to do so. Sorry if it wasn't clear: I want this external libs to be part of my Browserify bundle.

Comment: As long as you can `require()` it, Browserify will find it :-)

Comment: How can I require() an external lib? Making a require() with a relative path (require('../js/myLib.js')?

Comment: Yeah, that should be sufficient, although I would probably place it inside the project directory (so something like `require('./lib/myLib.js')`).

Comment: The only thing is that I must know how each library handle its dependencies and find each module and name it accordingly.

Comment: If the library itself depends on other libraries, then yes. Although I would assume that it would come with a `package.json` so you can `npm install`, and I think that Browserify will find those dependencies automatically for you.

Comment: Yes, but there's still some libraries that do not use any package system, such as npm or bower, and that makes things pretty hard...

Comment: You can mix browser-based libraries with bundles created by Browserify, if that makes things easier. Just load those libraries before your bundle.